# Can the same Social Club account be used for the Retail and Steam versions of GTA V?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Is it possible to use the same Social Club account (Rockstar) for a Steam game, if I have already redeemed (linked) GTA as a Retail game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Social Club account can be used anywhere you can log in with it. The platform you are logging in from does not matter.

Comment: Hmm. At first I thought it wouldn't be possible. But that makes sense. I was thinking about getting it on Steam so I don't have to go to the official site and download the game. But also I'd have synced saves and Steam achievements, right?

Comment: GTA V does not have Steam cloud saves so you will not have synced saves. You will get Steam Achievements, however.

Comment: So the next time I install GTA V, it won't download saved games from my last installation? Dammit.

Comment: Your save game will stay on the computer if you uninstall, so if you install it again on the same computer you will still have your save. If installing on another PC, you will not have the save.